# How to send email from a Flutter Web application?

Tags: email, dart, flutter-web

I'm trying to send email from a Flutter Web application using mailer package but I'm getting this error:

> Unsupported operation: Socket constructor

It seems like the package is dependent on dart:io which is not supported on Flutter Web. This is the the code that is meant to send email:

```
_sendEmail(String body) async {
print('Sending email...');
String username = 'myemail';
String password = 'mypassword';

final smtpServer = gmail(username, password);
final message = Message()
  ..from = Address(username, 'sender_name')
  ..recipients.add('reciever_email')
  ..subject = 'subject'
  ..text = body;

try {
  final sendReport = await send(message, smtpServer);
  print('message sent: ${sendReport.toString()}');
} catch (e) {
  print('message not sent: $e');
  e.problems.forEach(
    (element) => print('Problem: ${element.code}: ${element.msg}')
  );
}
```

I've used placeholders for credentials and I'm sure they're correct. Is there a way to send email from Flutter Web application?

Comment: Flutter Web are (as the name may indicate) running as JavaScript inside a web browser and is therefore limited to the capabilities that JavaScript can do. Since JavaScript cannot make TCP sockets it is not possible to implement the SMTP protocol in JavaScript. Since `mailer` seem to only be able to send mails using SMTP, you need to find another lib. You could look at the `googleapis` package which provides API's for Google Services like Google Mail. Since this package works by sending HTTP requests to Google, it will work in JavaScript and therefore Flutter Web.

Comment: Is there another way to do that? .. I want to send email by clicking a button automatically